# calculated measure grand total error

Tags: ssas

I have a calculated measure that works, but shows #VALUE! in Grand Total
in Browser in SSAS. The Current Forecast for months1-3 have no values and
greater than current month Qty Shipped contains no values when I drop those
measures in Browser to help debug.

```
case 
when [month part] >= [Current Month] then [Measures].[Current Forecast]
when [month part] < [Current Month] then  [Measures].[Qty Shipped]
else 0
end
```

Any help to what whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use ISEMPTY() function
Syntax

IIF(ISEMPTY(A) AND ISEMPTY(B), NULL, IIF(A=0 OR B = 0, 0, A/B)) i.e

IIF(

ISEMPTY([MEASURES].[A]) AND ISEMPTY([MEASURES].[B]), NULL,

IIF([MEASURES].[A] = 0 OR [MEASURES].[B]=0 , 0, [MEASURES].[A]/[MEASURES].  [B])

)

Comment: Do I use that with my current syntax or instead of ... not sure how to add the conditions.

 Thanks.

Comment: ISEMPTY([month part])  or ISEMPTY([Current Month])

Comment: I did this
IIF (ISEMPTY([month part]) or ISEMPTY([Current Month]),Null,IIF([month part] >= [Current Month],[Measures].[Current Forecast],null))
How do I get the other piece(IIF) of logic for Qty Shipped?  Thanks.

Comment: I tried .. to combine
IIF (ISEMPTY([month part]) or ISEMPTY([Current Month]),Null,IIF([month part] >= [Current Month],[Measures].[Current Forecast]),
 IIF (ISEMPTY([month part]) or ISEMPTY([Current Month]),Null,IIF([month part] < [Current Month].[Current Forecast])))

Syntax error too few argumenst for IIF